# How to establish Tcp connection between IOS and windows?

Tags: c++, objective-c, qt, ios, tcp

I'm trying to implement tcp connection between my Ipod as client and PC as server. I use QTcpServer to provide a server. What is the best way to realize the connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CFSocket. An awesome cocoa class has been written to wrap CFSocket for you asynchronously! It supports both UDP and TCP, I am using it myself in an IM application.

[AsyncSocket on iphone](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/wiki/iPhone)